# get id from a table, with a outside button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

well i have a html table, and a button next to it, i try to get the id from the table when the user click that button.
This is the HTML

```
<table id="table_domExtra2_pro" class="col m12 bordered striped centered ">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>No.</th>
        <th>PROPIETARIO DEL INMUEBLE</th>
        <th>REGIMEN DE PROPIEDAD</th>
        <th>COMO SE ACREDITA LA <br>POSESION DE LA PROPIEDAD</th>
        <th>SUPERFICIE DE <br>LA UNIDAD</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="count">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="propietario" id="propietario" type="text" class="validate" required>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="reg_propiedad" id="reg_propiedad" type="text" class="validate" required>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="pose_propiedad" id="pose_propiedad" type="text" class="validate" required>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="sup_unidad" id="sup_unidad" type="text" class="validate" required>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
     <div class="add_icon col s1 m6 ">
     <a id="btn_agregar_pro" class="btn waves-effect red">Agregar</a>
     </div>
     <div class="add_icon col s1 m6 ">
     <a id="btn_eliminar_pro" class="btn waves-effect red">Eliminar</a>
     </div>
```

This is the js

```
 $('#btn_eliminar_pro').on("click", function(){
    var idTable3 = $(this).parent().closest("table").attr("id");
    var trs4 = $("#"+idTable3+" tr").length;
    if(trs4 > 2){
      $("#table_domData_pro tr:last").remove();
      $("#table_domExtra_pro tr:last").remove();
      $("#table_domExtra2_pro tr:last").remove();
    }
  });
```

I try with  .prev() to, but Im really lost, i have other tables in the document and the js just select other table, not the one previus to the button, thanks a lot for your help :D

Comment: So `$(this).prev("table").attr("id")` didn't work?

Comment: No, that get undefined in the var idTable3 u_u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `siblings()` of the `div` to find the `closest` table. The below gets the `id` of the table. I have just added `siblings()` to your existing code.

```
var idTable3 = $(this).parent().siblings().closest("table").attr("id");
```